# Python Selenium wait function doesn't raise TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium wait has a 50 second set timeout, but sometimes it never raises an exception, it waits till I re-open the script, sometimes it waits for hours on end requiring me to connect to my server about every 2 hours or so. What might cause this? Is there a solution to this?

Driver options used:

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging','enable-automation'])
        
# For older ChromeDriver under version 79.0.3945.16
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

options.add_argument("window-size=1280,800")

#For ChromeDriver version 79.0.3945.16 or over
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Comment: What does your wait look like? Are you using both implicit waits and explicit waits? Sometimes if they clash they can cause issues

Comment: The wait looks like `wait.until(selEc.element_to_be_clickable((selBy.XPATH, <xpath of the component I want>)))` . And the timeout is 25 seconds but after sometime, it just doesn't work.